# Text on Progressbar

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display value in jQueryUI ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476542/display-value-in-jqueryui-progressbar)

How can I change the text on Progress Bar. I went through the following link but in vain.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

Any valuable input is helpful.